# Why am I getting this annoying problem in Multisim?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, matlab, multisim

I'm using the "edit model" button under the "value" tab of various components in Multisim. Some of the components give me a nice tabulated view of the components characteristics like saturation current, early voltage etc. However most of them just have a bunch of nonsense, an example of such given below. Could somebody tell me; what is this utter rubbish and how do I read it? I'm just trying to find some essential characteristcis of a P-type enhancement MOSFET in Multisim.

````
##################  Model Data Report  ##################

============= SPICE Model =================
*****************************************************************
* NXP PMXB75UPE
*
* Polarity P-Channel
* Ratings 20V/6.900000E-002OHMS/2.9A
*
* Date Created Fri Nov 15 05:37:49 2013
*
*****************************************************************
.SUBCKT PMXB75UPE/NXP DRAIN GATE SOURCE

LD DRAIN 5 5e-12
RLD2 DRAIN 5 0.0125663706143592
RLD1 5 4 1e-05
LG GATE 1 2.35111330977194e-10
RLG GATE 1 0.590899224138937
LS SOURCE 8 1.63386724749422e-10
RLS2 SOURCE 8 0.410635627333506
RLS1 8 7 0.0090317313748762

RDS 7 4 296735905.04451 TC=-0.005

RS 6 7 0.0001

RD 3 4 0.0472447167052708 TC=0.00330696474101549,4.37898233903176E-06
RBD 9 4 0.0785320295628481 TC=0.00330696474101549,4.37898233903176E-06
DBD 9 7 DBD

M1 3 2 6 6 MINT

RGS 2 6 2077922.07792208
CGS 2 6 5.446e-10
RG 1 2 11.27

* CGD
C11    11   12   1E-12
V11    11   0   0Vdc
G11    2 3 VALUE { V(13, 0)*I(V11) }
E11    12   0  2 3  1
E12    13   0  TABLE {V(12)}
+ -8    802.92399
+ -6    803.47299
+ -5    803.26899
+ -4    802.53999
+ -3    800.41399
+ -2    796.36499
+ -1    775.48799
+ -0.5  632.44599
+ -0.2  594.30999
+ -0.1  593.23899
+ 0 558.724195
+ 0.1   520.22952
+ 0.2   519.72532
+ 0.5   456.92324
+ 1 344.75228
+ 2 214.13028
+ 3 159.17068
+ 4 127.56152
+ 5 106.3498
+ 6 91.74974
+ 8 73.79069
+ 10    63.56052
+ 12    57.07183
+ 15    50.74937
+ 16    49.11552
+ 20    44.62919



.MODEL MINT PMOS(Vto=-1.03952683413131 Kp=2.900107e+001 Nfs=242500000000 Eta=5900
+ Level=3 L=1e-4 W=1e-4 Gamma=0 Phi=0.6 Is=1e-24
+ Js=0 Pb=0.8 Cj=0 Cjsw=0 Cgso=0 Cgdo=0 Cgbo=0
+ Tox=1e-07 Xj=0
+ U0=600 Vmax=390)

.MODEL DBD D(Bv=25.7 Ibv=2.500000E-004 Rs=1E-6 Is=6.01232987820719e-11
+ N=1 M=0.710000000000001 VJ=0.63 Fc=0.5 Cjo=8.02833900000001e-11 Tt=1.85e-08)

.ENDS

============= Model template =================
x%p %tD %tG %tS %m
```
````

Comment: This is a SPICE model. It's a language used for expressing the behavior of electronic components.

Comment: It's a SPICE netlist. SPICE dates from an era of punched card decks and FORTRAN, not relatively readable syntax.

Comment: Bossting, SPICE was designed back when there were no CRTs nor flat panel displays. Just alphanumeric hard copy devices (basically, a typewriter that is hooked up to a computer.) So the first character of a line would determine the model. An "R" is a resistor, a "C" is a capacitor, etc. They reserved a special case using the letter "X" as a "call subroutine" kind of thing. You might write "X1 N1 N2 N3 MYSUB" in a line. This just means to call MYSUB (a .SUBCKT block of "code") replacing three subroutine parameters with "N1", "N2", and "N3", in that order. It's a "subcircuit."

Comment: Bossting, so you can by hand read that .SUBCKT subroutine and actually hand-layout the associated schematic for it, if you want to go to the trouble. You can then see what the designer intended more easily. It's a pain. But these are usually used to create more "accurate" models with all the associated parasitics added in, or a wider range of operation. Sometimes, more sophisticated levels of models are available for mosfets, for example. And one may avoid the need for a .SUBCKT if the fancier models include the needed parasitics. But even then there are times when more is needed for accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't nonsense at all; it's a SPICE model, in this specific case, a subcircuit model. SPICE models take the form of a sort of hardware description language designed for analog circuitry; subcircuits are easy to understand as simply the netlist of an equivalent circuit.

For more information, since I'm by no means an expert on SPICE, [here](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/)'s a rundown of the basics I found after a brief search.

Comment: If I may add one remark, it's probably worth mentioning that the "essential characteristics" the OP is looking for aren't expressed directly in the SPICE as a single number each; they are often the approximation of considering multiple phenomena that the much larger SPICE model can represent more precisely than those individual parameters can.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks for explaining that. So if I understand it correctly trying to read this SPICE stuff is basically useless for me in finding the characteristics I want?

Comment: @Bossting correct, it's likely not useful although I'm not sure which characteristics you're looking for. Your characteristics will only be an approximation/simplification of the spice model anyway, and only a few of them might be directly present as a number you can pull from the code.

Comment: @Bossting Not useless, but it would take a lot more effort to figure them out than it's worth. You could do it faster by just hooking up the model in such a way as to measure the characteristics.

Answer (score 3):

As others have already mentioned, this is a standard SPICE model. All the parameters you said you want are actually in the model! In summary, the anatomy of a SPICE model consists of some standard parts which are usually an intimate and inbuilt part of the simulator and additional components that you can connect to them.

Examples of inbuilt models are transistors, diodes, resistors etc which you can invoke and then connect these to additional components to model more complicated non-ideal behaviour. This is what the model you have attached is basically doing.

In this case ignoring the rest of the model which simply models additional parasitic components, look at this line:

> MODEL MINT PMOS(Vto=-1.03952683413131 Kp=2.900107e+001 Nfs=242500000000 Eta=5900 Level=3 L=1e-4 W=1e-4 Gamma=0 Phi=0.6 Is=1e-24 Js=0 Pb=0.8 Cj=0 Cjsw=0 Cgso=0 Cgdo=0 Cgbo=0  Tox=1e-07 Xj=0 U0=600 Vmax=390)

This is invoking a standard PMOS model (so called level 3 model) where most parameters you should be able to identify, such as threshold, breakdown voltage, early effect because this model is relatively simple and closer to the square-law models you may have learnt about. Note this is in general not possible for more complicated models, i.e all parameters do not necessarily have an intuitive physics based interpretation, they are just there as parameters to fit the empirical data better.

So if you want to ever extract parameters from a model, my best advice is to set up a simple test bench and conduct a test that somehow spits out a parameter you are interested in. For example, for early voltage, it is better to set up a IDS vs VDS sweep test and calculate the effective early voltage from the data.

Comment: Here is a link to what all these parameters mean, you will probably be able to identify most of them: http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/ads2008/ccnld/ads2008/LEVEL3_Model_(MOSFET_Level-3_Model).html

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers/comments hinted at it, but I thought I'd make it more clear by addressing the original premise for the question.  I'm not super familiar with Multisim, but based on the context it sounds like when a component's model is defined simply using a SPICE "modelcard" (i.e. a `.model` statement) Multisim will show you the tabulated values for each SPICE parameter for that intrinsic model.  As you mentioned, this seems to be the case with most of your other semiconductors, such as diodes and BJTs.

However, discrete vertical diffused MOSFETs (i.e. VDMOS FETs) require a subcircuit to be properly modeled due to its unique construction.  The intrinsic models for MOSFETs within SPICE were designed for monolithic (integrated circuit) MOSFETs only (NOTE: look up what `SPICE` stands for).  So what manufacturers do is build a complicated subcircuit around a monolithic MOSFET to correctly model a discrete MOSFET.  The exception to this rule is that [LTspice](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html) created its own proprietary model called `VDMOS` (NOTE: [ngspice](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/) has also adopted this model type).  Almost all other SPICE-based programs, such as Multisim, still require the use of subcircuits for discrete MOSFETs.  Also, to ensure cross-compatibility across various SPICE programs, manufacturers will typically provide a universal subcircuit SPICE model for download on their websites.

Therefore, since your NXP PMXB75UPE is a discrete MOSFET, Multisim pulls up the subcircuit definition since it can't be correctly defined with only monolithic MOSFET parameters.  This is likely going to happen will all the built-in discrete MOSFETs within Multisim.  If you need to extract parameters, you can look at the underlying [monolithic model's parameters](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/UserGuide/elements.html#668) (listed after the `.MODEL MINT PMOS(` for the PMXB75UPE) and/or build simulation test-benches to extract what you need.  Both of these approaches are mentioned in further detail in other answers.